# quick way to add a vertex and an edge

Tags: modeling

What is a quick(er) way to create a vertex for this scenario:

My start is this:

[image]

Then i subdivide and move my vertex:

[image]

then i create an edge with J:

[image]

then i dissolve the edge:

[image]

So what i basically would like to do:

Double that vertex and edge slide it (with the edge) to get the end result.

Is there a quicker way than my laborious way?

Comment: Not that I know. A different way, yes... The Alt+V method from @karlaton might be a bit quicker then subdividing, you just have to position the mouse cursor correctly to split the vertex in the desired direction. But still you would have to dissolve the edge, or select both faces and press F. But I guess what works best or quickest is likely to give opinion-based answers.

Comment: I just realised I answered the question without looking at the user asking. :D Well... It might be directed at a less advanced user. But the Alt+D thing is useful...

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys: I am happy i am not alone with this "lazy" reading. I did often post answers - which weren't really related to the question because i read "too" fast and too bad. Maybe i am the one here with the most deleted answers :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the vertex and press alt + V, then drag it along.
You will still need to dissolve the other edge.

Could try the knife tool too, K then two clicks. Not necessarily quicker, but less chance of accidentally moving the geometry, which might happen with alt + V method

Comment: When I would use the Alt+V method, I would do it like this: Alt+V then right-click to abort so you don't move the vertex accidentally. Then double G to slide along the edge.

Answer (score 6):

These are very quick actions - they take seconds. It's a bit strange to call this laborious. You can use keyboard shortcuts for this. You do not need to wait for right-click menu to appear to press <kbd>S</kbd> for subdivide, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to dissolve as well so these every-day modelling actions should be quite comfortable:

[image]

You could use the knife tool(<kbd>k</kbd>) to create the vert in place and connect it to the other one with an edge. You do somewhat loose precision of placement of the vert because you can't use all snapping functionality you could with transform operations. Axis constraining works with with knife tool though:

[image]

You could also use Auto Merge with Split Edges and Faces enabled so you could simply duplicate the vert(<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) and move it. It will get disconnected, but it will split the edge if you place it exactly on the edge so if you can constrain the transform in the direction of the edge that might be it. You need the edge to match one of the axis, or have a custom transform orientation made from the edge before, but it's possible:

[image]

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> calls an operator that is called Extend Vertices. It is sensitive to mouse position, so you need the mouse to be in the triangle for it to work:

[image]

Comment: Using the knife method but in face mode, then selecting the 2 faces and hitting `f` is a slightly faster way

Comment: @Psyonic not sure I follow. Knife tool has no hotkey F as far as I can tell, face fill requires 2 clicks for the selection while dissolving an edge requires only one click to select the edge and extending the vert doesn't even leave an edge...

Comment: Oh true! The ALT-D method is much faster! I was referring to selecting the faces after the knife tool then hitting `F`, based on your knife tool example. But doing it in edge mode would be faster still :)

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys: First: I see myself more like an amateur modeller - it's not really my everyday work - that's why i am asking. I have to learn a lot in that area ;) thank you for your answer, i learned some new shortcuts! But for me it looks like karlaton's answer is a bit faster. Anyway you got an upvote for your great answer. Well...everything will become laborious if you have to do it hundreds of times - and then you will be thankful for every click/keyboard press you can do less ;)

Comment: I learned something really useful from your first GIF. Somehow I didn't know about `J` ([Connect Vertex Path](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/vertex/connect_vertex_path.html)), and had been using `K` (Knife) for that sort of operation all these years.